# self.view not properly aligned on window

Tags: iphone, uiwindow

So what I am really doing is... I have a login page, when proper login session took place, Its navigating to another view. It contains Tab bar. So what I did is, I made a separate class for customizing 'UITabbarController'. And now I see a white screen on the top and below is the view of that class.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Can you post the code please, because what you are saying, its simply not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you subclassing UITTabBarController?  It is not something you would normally want to do.

A better option is to create your second viewcontroller and add a normal UITabBarController onto that viewcontroller's view.